# How does Cleacase knows that a directory is a view?

Tags: windows, view, get, clearcase, snapshot

I am working with a clearcase snapshot view under windows. I am trying to download the content of a file file.txt which is not loaded by my current configspec.
My snapshot view is c:\view.

The following command
`cleartool get -to toto.txt someCorrectVOBdir\file.txt`

works perfectly when called from c:\view, and fails when called from any non-view directory with the error
`cleartool: Error: Operation "get cleartext" failed: not a ClearCase object.`

Why? How can clearcase knows that the current directory is not a view directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClearCase check for a **`view.dat` hidden file**, either in the current directory or in a parent directory.

If it finds one, the current directory is part of a snapshot view.
if it doesn't find one, this isn't a ClearCase view.

If the `view.dat` is somehow erased and lost, [it can be regenerated](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/to_regenerate_viewdat.htm).

Comment: @kolslorr: for the very few CC there is on SO... yes ;)

Comment: After reading the site VonC provided, I found some intersting page:[How snapshot views are distinguished from standard directories](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/how_distinguish_ssv.htm), [About locating snapshot view root directories](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_rootdir_ssv.htm)